# Adress Generator: Bit Swapping Problem (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, vivado

what I want to do is the following:

In order to generate the appropriate OUTPUT I have to add a value(2^(stage-small_p+1) to my INPUT and then swapping the LSB (0) with a bit, which position depends on a the difference between the stage-signal and the constant small_p (stage-small_p).

Thanks for your help!

```
PROCESS(INPUT,stage)

BEGIN

    IF stage > small_p THEN

    OUTPUT_sig<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(to_integer(UNSIGNED(INPUT)+2** 
    (stage-small_p+1)),m));

        bit_0 <= OUTPUT_SIG(0);

        bit_sp <=OUTPUT_SIG(stage-small_p);

        FOR i in 0 to m-1 LOOP

            IF (i=0) THEN
               OUTPUT(i)<=bit_sp ;
            ELSIF (i=(stage-small_p)) THEN
                OUTPUT(i)<=bit_0;
            ELSE
                OUTPUT(i)<=OUTPUT_SIG(i);
        END IF;

        END LOOP;

    ELSE
        OUTPUT <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0,m));
    END IF;
```

The error seems to be when assigning OUTPUT_SIG(i) to OUTPUT(i):
For example stage = 9 and p_small = 4: 
My INPUT is                           00110010,
OUTPUT_SIG has the value:             01110010, 
whereas the OUTPUT has the value:     01010101.
stage-small_p = 5, so I would expect: 01010011 (Bit 5 and Bit 0 swapped).

Comment: Note the lack of a [mcve], your problem can't easily be duplicated. There's also a lack of an intervening wait statement between the assignment to OUTPUT_sig and where OUTPUT_sig is evaluated.  No signal is updated while any process has yet to resume and subsequently suspend in the current simulation cycle. Perhaps instead of signal OUTPUT_sig you should be using a variable? Every evaluated signal should be present in the sensitivity list, is small_p a signal?

Comment: [corrected and modified process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9faYe.jpg)